# Deploying an RSA Machine-Level Key Container to Encrypt a Connection String in Web.Config using Octopus Deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, encryption, octopus-deploy

I have a web farm scenario. I want to encrypt customer bank details in our database. I have [a fairly good understanding of the encryption requirements](http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/06/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-7.html), but the hard challenge is secure key storage.

Microsoft suggests that the best way to do this is to use "[RSA with a Machine-Level Key Container to Encrypt a Connection String in Web.Config](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998283.aspx)".

Whilst the implementation of this appears to be relatively trivial, or easy enough to follow, I'm wondering if anyone has attempted to do this during deployment using Octopus Deploy?

My assumption is that I need to make the various aspnet_regiis.exe calls using the install.ps Powershell script.

Any suggestions or code sample would be gladly welcomed if you have already solved this problem.

Comment: I am trying to achieve same results. Did you manage to implement any solution?